# onclick function to change url - not working everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, jquery-events, location-href

I have four links each with an onclick event, each pass their language code to the changeLanguage function. The function should remove everything after the last '/' of the URL and replace it with the new language code and then redirect to the address. It works about 60/70% of the time, but if it doesn't the page reloads the current page. I've tried `window.location.href`, `window.location.replace`, timeouts. It seems random as well, it could happen changing from any country. Any ideas?

e.g. from console:

(On French page)

```
http://localhost:4000/product/fr
```

(change to Spanish - worked)

```
NEW URL http://localhost:4000/product/es

Navigated to http://localhost:4000/product/es
```

(change to English - didn't work)

```
NEW URL http://localhost:4000/product/en

Navigated to http://localhost:4000/product/es
```

HTML

```
  <ul class="social-links">
      <li class="lang"><a id='en-lang-nav-button' onclick="return changeLanguage('en', event)" <%if(data.lang.lang == 'en'){%> class="active"<%}%>><%=data.lang.links[0].text%></a> | </li>

      <li class="lang"><a id='fr-lang-nav-button' onclick="return changeLanguage('fr', event)" <%if(data.lang.lang == 'fr'){%> class="active"<%}%>><%=data.lang.links[1].text%></a> | </li>

      <li class="lang"><a id='sp-lang-nav-button' onclick="return changeLanguage('es', event)" <%if(data.lang.lang == 'es'){%> class="active"<%}%>><%=data.lang.links[2].text%></a> | </li>

      <li class="lang"><a id='pt-lang-nav-button' onclick="return changeLanguage('pt', event)" <%if(data.lang.lang == 'pt'){%> class="active"<%}%>><%=data.lang.links[3].text%></a> </li>
  </ul>
```

JS

```
  function changeLanguage(lang, event) {
      var index, newURL;
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      index = window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/');
      newURL = window.location.href.substring(0, index) + '/' + lang;  

      console.log('NEW URL', newURL);
      window.location = newURL; 
      return false;
   };
```

Standard route in BE:

```
router.get('/about/:lang(en|fr|es|pt)?', function(req, res, next) {
    trackPath(req);
    res.render('about', { data: router.getTemplateData(req.params.lang, 'about') });
});
```

Comment: did you try changing the browser? which browser are you using?

Comment: Using Chrome, but its needs to be compatible with all browsers ideally

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the problem is due to the same id. Element `<a>` of `es` and `pt` are the same.

```
<li class="lang"><a id='sp-lang-nav-button' onclick="return changeLanguage('es', event)" <%if(data.lang.lang == 'es'){%> class="active"<%}%>><%=data.lang.links[2].text%></a> | </li>

<li class="lang"><a id='sp-lang-nav-button' onclick="return changeLanguage('pt', event)" <%if(data.lang.lang == 'pt'){%> class="active"<%}%>><%=data.lang.links[3].text%></a> </li>
```

Are you running it in a web server?

Comment: Thanks, good spot. I just changed it, but it made no difference. Yes running locally, its a node server, no front end framework, just js and jquery.

Comment: Could you show the code of back end, I think that maybe the problem is not from front end but from back end

Comment: Added a standard route to the bottom of the above

Comment: hi, I tried it and it worked well, BackEnd Framework I used Express.

Comment: You may remove router, just read `*.html` with `fs` module and try it again to help you find problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to alter the BE code, so I tried the below, which works:

```
      $('li.lang a').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            var lang = ['/en', '/fr', '/es', '/pt'], 
                location = window.location.href,
                chosenLang = $(this).parent().attr('id');

            // Check url for a lang code
            for(var i = 0; i < lang.length; i++) {
                if (location.indexOf(lang[i]) >= 0) {
                  window.location.href = location.replace(lang[i], '/' + chosenLang);
                  return false;
                } 
            }
            // If no lang code in url
            window.location.href = location.replace('#', '') + '/' + chosenLang;
            return false;
        });
```

If anyone can condense it, I'd love to see!